# Remove space between currency and price Magento1.9

Tags: price, magento1.9.3

When I switch the stores from `English to Dutch` or any other I got spaces between currency and prices. It's on the whole site so I think some theme related issue.I recently updated `Magento` from `1.9` to `1.9.3`. I tried by getting prices on the product page with custom code but no luck. I am sharing the screenshot of the issue.[image]

This space coming on `RWD` and `Default` themes too.

Answer (score 0):

1) Need to find this file :

  1. Log into your Magento Admin Backend.

  2. Go to System ->> Configuration.

  3. Click on "Developer" in the left side menu pane.

  4. Open the "Debug" section.

  5. Change the "Profiler" to "Yes"

  6. Click "Save Config"

2) Сlean the cache and you will see the path where this block lies. Example : [image]

3) If you do not see a space or any characters, try to delete everything and write the code again. (This may be an invisible symbol, I somehow copied the URL from Skype, and at the end of the URL a symbol was added

Example:   `echo $block->getBaseUrl().'privacy-policy-gdpr /'`

I hope that my answer will bring you closer to the solution.

Comment: It showing me this block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price` and base  path for price.